# the maximum of the mininums of all the k subsequences

Tags: c++, arrays, minimum

You have a sequence of n elements. Find the maximum of all the minimums taken from contiguous subsequences of k elements. 
I tried the classical way in which you take all the sequences of length k. And then take the minimums. And find the maximum of the new array of minimums.

A more optimal solution would be to find the minimum od the first k elemnts and then jump exactly after it. And you skip some iterations.

Can you give me a better and obtimal solution? 
Doesn't matter, but I am using C++.

Comment: Is it an excersize? A programming contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, While this may be an assignment, I will like you to have a feel of a generic and neat STL-style of doing these things.

```
template<typename Iter, typename T = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>
std::pair<T, T> KConsecutiveMinMax(Iter first, Iter last, std::size_t K){
    if(std::distance(first, last) < K) return {};

    auto Sum = std::accumulate(first, first+K, T());
    auto Min = Sum;
    auto Max = Sum;
    for(auto left = first, right = first + K; right != last; Sum -= *left++, Sum += *right++)
        std::tie(Min, Max) = std::minmax(std::min(Min, Sum), std::max(Max, Sum));
    return {Min, Max};
}
```

It adds the first `K` elements of the array, assigns them to `Sum`, `Max` and `Min`, then adds the `K+1`th element while subtracting the tail element. For each of this, it extracts the the new `Min` and `Max` of the sum of the new local subsequence

Example:

```
int main(){
    std::vector<int> v{2, 39, 1, 9, 8, 6, 3, 10, -42, 3, 8, 3, 2};
    auto ans = KConsecutiveMinMax(v.begin(), v.end(), 3);
    std::cout << "Min = " << ans.first << ", and Max = " << ans.second << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Min = -31, and Max = 49
> ```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cba4beeb03ad636b)